# What I do with the results extracted from lasso?

Tags: stata, lasso

**Summarize the problem**

I have a dataset with panel data and I am trying to make variable selection. I have tried lasso technique. Lasso proposed me a list of variables that could be included in the model.

What I do not understand is how should I use them. For example in stata I run the following :

```
lasso lpsa lcavol lweight age lbph svi lcp gleason pgg45
lassocoef
```

Lasso lists for me a number of variables

lcavol

lweight

svi

**What would I expect**

When I try to run a regression using the model lpsa~lcavol +lweight+svi to receive results demonstrating that lcavol, lweight and svi are significant predictors of lpsa.

```
regress lpsa lcavol lweight svi
```

Can you help me understand what tests should I do with the variables selected by lasso in order to ensure that the model is suitable?

Answer (score 1):

Lasso can be used for prediction/model selection (PL) or inference (IL) problems.  By model selection I just mean finding a model that fits the data, not finding a model that allows for interpreting estimated coefficients. You can learn more about that distinction [in the lasso intro](https://www.stata.com/manuals/lassolassointro.pdf) and choose your adventure accordingly.

If your goal is prediction, you should predict. That's about all that can be done (other than checking some model diagnostics and goodness of fit). There's a general PL info [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals/lassolasso.pdf#lassolasso). Take a look [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals/lassolassoexamples.pdf#lassolassoexamples) for some PL examples to guide you.

If your want to conduct inference that is robust to the variable selection part, you should use `xporegress` instead (or maybe `dpregress` or `poregress`) instead of vanilla `lasso`. This will return coefficients, standard errors, p-values, and CIs for specified variables of interest and uses lasso to select the other covariates (controls) that need to appear in the model from the potential control variables you specify. You can conduct hypothesis tests, stare at the coefficients, and interpret their economic significance. You can interpret these results in the same way you might interpret results from standard regression models. These inference methods are robust to model-selection mistakes that lasso might make. This should work if the true variables are among the potential control variables that you have specified and there aren't too many true variables (sparsity assumption). There's general IL info [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals/lassolassoinferenceintro.pdf). Take a look here for [some IL examples](https://www.stata.com/manuals/lassoinferenceexamples.pdf).

When you just run OLS on the variables that survive regularisation that's not so good from the inference perspective, which the links above will explain in more detail. The SEs will be too small, and you will mistakenly omit true covariates with small coefficients, which can bias other coefficients.

Now for some additional comments about your approach.

You should definitely consider adding lots of interactions between your variables using factor variables notation. You can go wild here.

You might also think about using `npregress` if you know the control variables but not the functional form in which they appear in the true model (including interactions).